# How to set class attribute for elements with document contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

With a div contenteditable, when executing `document.execCommand('insertImage', null, img_url);`, it will add an image element in that div, but is there any way to add a class attribute for that image element? I don't think insertHTML is a good solution for compatibility issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could use CSS CLass applier: http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/CSSClassApplierModule